# Adding elements to a text file using Matlab

Tags: matlab

suppose I have an text file consisting of the following arrays:

```
[1]
[1, 2, 6, 7, 4]
[1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 6, 5, 7, 4]
[1, 2, 6, 5, 7, 8, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 8, 6, 7, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 8, 6, 5, 7, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 6, 7, 4]
[2, 6, 7, 8, 3, 4]
[2, 6, 5, 7, 4]
[2, 6, 5, 7, 8, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 8, 6, 7, 4]
[2, 3, 8, 6, 5, 7, 4]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 8]
[8, 6, 7]
[8, 6, 5, 7]
[5]
```

I want to append the first element of each array to the end of the corresponding array.
I want my output to look something like this:

```
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 6, 7, 4, 1]
[1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 3, 4, 1]
[1, 2, 6, 5, 7, 4, 1]
[1, 2, 6, 5, 7, 8, 3, 4, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 8, 6, 7, 4, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 8, 6, 5, 7, 4, 1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
[2, 6, 7, 4, 2]
[2, 6, 7, 8, 3, 4, 2]
[2, 6, 5, 7, 4, 2]
[2, 6, 5, 7, 8, 3, 4, 2]
[2, 3, 8, 6, 7, 4, 2]
[2, 3, 8, 6, 5, 7, 4, 2]
[2, 3, 4, 2]
[3, 8, 3]
[8, 6, 7, 8]
[8, 6, 5, 7, 8]
[5, 5]
```

How do I do this in matlab?

Comment: You know the steps involved: read a line of the text file, copy the first array element to the end, write the line to the output file. Which part is not working for you? Do you have any code that you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

My Matlab (2014b) does not support text in a string as the 2016 and onwards does. I cannot test, but [based on this page](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-string-arrays.html) the procedure shown below should be usable as well, just make the proper adaptation of cell to string array.
I will put as comment, but i can't yet. It is convenient to show explicitly how is your data, e.g.,

```
str = ["Mercury","Gemini","Apollo";
   "Skylab","Skylab B","ISS"]
```

or

```
a={'alpha','beta','gamma'};
```

A usual way of having matrixes of different size is using a cell array. If it is the case, you could do something like:

```
a={'alpha','beta','gamma'};
for i=1:numel(a), 
      a{i}=strcat(a{i},a{i}(1)); 
end
a = 
   'alphaa'    'betab'    'gammag'
```

If another format, you could adjust the call of the text accordingly.

Also, in the part (Split, Join, and Sort String Array) of [the same link as above](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-string-arrays.html), you may have the answer in a simpler way (but i cannot test).

Edit1: made a mistake on the interpretation!

Comment: the data type is a string

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet does the trick:

```
fid = fopen('filename.txt');
line1 = fgetl(fid);
p =str2num(line1);
a=[p,p(1)];
while ischar(line1)
    line1 = fgetl(fid);
    if line1(1)==-1
        break;
    end
    p=str2num(line1);
    a=[p,p(1)];
end
fclose(fid);
```